# HTML Tabs Showing All content

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I am using html tabs on a custom page that integrates with my wordpress site.

The code below is for setting up tabs but all the content from each tab is coming through on all the tabs and not just the specific area it is for.

The code below pulls in javascript from an external source.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Example of Bootstrap 3 Dynamic Tabs</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <style type="text/css">
        .bs-example{
            margin: 20px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="bs-example">
        <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
            <li class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#sectionA">Section A</a></li>
            <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#sectionB">Section B</a></li>
        </ul>
        <div class="tab-content">
            <div id="sectionA" class="tab-pane fade in active" style="padding-top:100px">
               <p>Testing Section A</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="tab-content">
            <div id="sectionB" class="tab-pane fade in" style="padding-top:100px">
               <p>Testing Section B</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you please make your question bit more clear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try with this HTML markup. It should work.

```
<div class="bs-example">
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
        <li class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#sectionA">Section A</a></li>
        <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#sectionB">Section B</a></li>
    </ul>

    <div class="tab-content">
        <div id="sectionA" class="tab-pane fade in active" style="padding-top:100px">
           <p>Testing Section A</p>
        </div>
        <div id="sectionB" class="tab-pane fade in" style="padding-top:100px">
           <p>Testing Section B</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi Thanks for your answer could you please tell me why a php scrip like the one below throw up the same problem
<div class="bs-example">
  <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#sectionA">Section A</a></li>
    <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#sectionB">Section B</a></li>
  </ul>
  <div class="tab-content">
    <div id="sectionA" class="tab-pane fade in active" style="padding-top:100px">
     <?php print file_get_contents("http://housepubandkitchen.com/breakfastmenu")?>
    </div>

Comment: I suspect you have a invalid HTML markup in http://housepubandkitchen.com/breakfastmenu/ . I can see extra </div> before <div class="content-wrapper">. Try removing that extra </div> and check.

Comment: I love you Buddy Fresh Eyes always help

Answer (score 1):

You only need to define the `tab-content` div once, you are doing it twice.

```
<div class="bs-example">
  <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#sectionA">Section A</a></li>
    <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#sectionB">Section B</a></li>
  </ul>
  <div class="tab-content">
    <div id="sectionA" class="tab-pane fade in active" style="padding-top:100px">
      <p>Testing Section A</p>
    </div>
    <div id="sectionB" class="tab-pane fade in" style="padding-top:100px">
      <p>Testing Section B</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

See this [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/q2405teL/) which I created using your code which demonstrates how it should work.

Comment: Thanks for your help your answer solved the first problem and now what I want to do is use a php print scrip to display a page instead of text section A see on the page here http://housepubandkitchen.com/paulspage/

<div class="tab-content">
    <div id="sectionA" class="tab-pane fade in active" style="padding-top:100px">
     <?php print file_get_contents("http://housepubandkitchen.com/breakfastmenu")?>
    </div>

Comment: Sorry i've never worked with PHP before so can't help you. If you've attempted something and it hasn't worked then i'd suggest to create a new question. It would also be nice if you could accept this as the correct answer if it helped you :)

Comment: Thanks for your help Buddy

Answer (score 0):

Maybe trying to cut the script files from the head of the HTML file and place them just before the closing body tag.

Try looking at the mark up of bootstrap http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#template

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have to make it this way:

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
   <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="#sectionA" aria-controls="sectionA" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Section A</a></li>
   <li role="presentation"><a href="#sectionB" aria-controls="sectionB" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Section B</a></li>
</ul>

<div class="tab-content">
    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane active" id="sectionA">...</div>
    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="sectionB">...</div>
</div>
```

For your reference:
http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tabs